# How to calculate the time it takes two trains to stop after decelerating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

The problem statement is as follows:

> Two trains, each traveling at $30\,\mathrm{ft}/\mathrm{sec}$, approach each other on a straight track. When they are $1000$ feet apart, a bee begins flying from one train to the other and back again at the rate of $60\,\mathrm{ft}/\mathrm{sec}$, and continues to do so until the trains crash. How far does the bee fly before it is crushed by the crashing trains?

It consists of three parts, I was able to solve the first two parts of the problem. The last part however is what I got stuck at. It goes like:

> Suppose the conductors of the two trains see each other and hit the brakes when they are $180$ feet apart. If both trains decelerate at the rate of $5 \, \text{ft}/\text{sec}^{2}$, how far does the bee fly before the trains come together?

My attempt was to first calculate the time it takes the trains travel before decelerating and that is
$$\dfrac{1000-180}{60}=\dfrac{820}{60} \, \text{s}$$

the part that I am stuck in is how to calculate the time they travel before stopping, in my solution manual it is said that it takes them $6$ seconds until they completely stop, how did we find that exactly? I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: Basically you are asking how long it takes to go from 30 ft/s to 0 ft/s if you slow down 5 ft/s every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v(t)=v(0)+at$ you know $v(0)$. You know $a$ and you want the time for $v(t)=0$
($a$ is negative, so $a=-5ft/s^2$)